# How to @Autowire a bean which is hidden behind ProxyFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, interceptor, autowired

Let's say we have two beans, defined in Spring

```xml
<bean class="foo.A"/>
<bean class="foo.B"/>
```

```java
public class A {
   @Autowired
   private B b;
}

public class B {
   public void foo() {
      ...
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve is the interception of all calls to `B.foo()`. Looking at documentation, I wrote interceptor `C` and changed the definition of bean `B` as follows:

```java
public class C implements org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice {
    public void before(final Method method, final Object[] args, final Object target) {
        // interception logic goes here
    }
}
```

```xml
<bean class="foo.C"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
    <property name="singleton" value="false"/>
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="foo.B" scope="prototype"/>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>foo.C</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Problem:** when starting up, Spring container complains: *No matching bean of type [foo.B] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency*. In other words, it  can't inject `B` into `A` because `B` is hidden behind *org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean* and no longer "automagically" recognized. If I replace the definition into a simple `class=foo.B`, container starts fine. What's the best way to solve this?

**Bonus question:** is it possible to implement interception of `B.foo()` without involvement of `ProxyFactoryBean` and only using annotations (preferably without involvement of `<aop:...`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define an interface for `foo.B` (e.g. `foo.BInterface`) and use `foo.BInterface` in the class A.

Also pay attention that `Autowired` injections are done only once. So if `foo.A` is singleton, it will receive only the first created instance of `foo.B`, while you want it to be a prototype.

**Answer to bonus**: Yes, but it may be more complicated. As a possible solution you can implement `BeanPostProcessor`. In the implementation you can replace the foo.B with dynamic proxy. So basically you do the same, but instead of using `<aop:` you do it yourself using basic Spring functionality. And again: you don't solve the "prototype is not autowired" problem and you still need an interface.

Comment: I do have an interface for foo.B, so are you saying I should use a @Qualifier? And thanks for the warning - but bean A is also a prototype (which is always instantiated fresh when necessary), so I think I should be fine.

Comment: No, I didn't say @Qualifier. IMO, if @Qualifier is needed, it's better not to use @Autowired at all. So you say that in class A you already use BInterface?

Comment: But what if foo.B is not the only implementor of foo.BInterface?

Comment: You'll get an exception... Just don't use @Autowired in this case. Inject it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to have the Bean 'foo.B' defined outside of the `ProxyFactoryBean`, and refer to it from the target property.

```
<bean class="foo.C"/>
<bean id="fooB" class="foo.B" scope="prototype"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
   <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
   <property name="singleton" value="false"/>
   <property name="target" ref="fooB"/>
   <property name="interceptorNames">
      <list>
         <value>foo.C</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I think the original bean (without AOP interceptor) will be injected in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Tarlog's answer is correct, but to make it more clear:
you should wire objects by their interface, not by their class:

```
public class A {
   @Autowired
   private C b;
}

public class B implements C{
   public void foo() {
      ...
   }
}
```